# Can we have MathJax enabled?

Tags: feature-request, support

Cardano is unlike other cryptocurrencies, in that it's development is significantly based on [research papers as listed on the organization's site](https://iohk.io/en/research/library/). Many of these publications involve math.

On MMSE we got MathJax enabled [within 2 hours](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3/5), presumably because we asked for it early, while we had Adam Lear's attention during Private Beta. On Drones.SE which entered Beta in the same month, [it took several months](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/q/194/3) to get the MathJax request [status-completed](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Therefore, can we get MathJax enabled?

---

In response to Catija's request to see some examples of where MathJax would be useful, since we're still in the first few hours of Private Beta and don't have many questions yet, I've got some examples from Bitoin.SE (already 3 posts so far, without doing extensive research so far, and without searching other cryptocurrency sites like Etherium.SE, EOS.IO, Tezos.SE, Iota.SE, Monero.SE, etc.):

- https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/84032/90058
- https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/22984/90058
- https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/57481/90058

Comment: Do you have any examples of questions that actually need MathJax? If the site's subject isn't heavily reliant on it in an obvious way, we tend to need proof that it's needed.

Comment: @Catija Not yet (there's been only a few questions so far), but also people might avoid writing things that would need MathJax, if MathJax is not yet enabled. I also foresee it being used: Not as much as on Mathematics.SE but at least as much as on 3D Printing or Blender. MathJax isn't as hard to enable, nor as hindering to the speed of loading a page, as most people seem to think. I've added some examples from Bitcoin.SE though, and could do it for Etherium.SE, Tezos.SE, Iota.SE, Monero.SE etc. but it will take a while, since it's not exactly easy to search for MathJax when there's no MathJax

Comment: @Catija There are occasionally formulas to be explained for items such as how rewards and voting results are calculated, various voting systems, network theory, etc.  that justify its inclusion.

Comment: @Catija An example from Cardano: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/821/149 (probably not the only one, I just came across this while doing close reviews).

Comment: Another example from today's reviews: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/852/149